# Attribute Error : Can't pickle local object

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am making a chatbot using pytorch. I developed this chatbot on a linux system which was working flawlessly. But when i am running the same model in windows 10. There is an error :-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
> return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).**call**(environ,
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
> response = self.handle_exception(e)
> return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
> raise value
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
> raise value
> rv = self.dispatch_request()
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint                      > load(candidateSkillset.get(name))
> File
> for (words, labels_net) in train_loader:
> return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
> w.start()
> self._popen = self._Popen(self)
> return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
> return Popen(process_obj)
> reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
> ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'load..ChatDataset'
> exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
> self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
> EOFError: Ran out of input

I am calling the function with the dataset i want it to train on... Here is my code :-

```
def load(inp):
    
    global words,labels,doc_x,doc_y,questionsP1,questionsP2,questionsP3,questionsP4,model,questionTag, all_words, tags, xy, questions_list
    
    all_words=[]
    tags=[]
    xy=[]
    questions_list = []

    words=[]
    labels=[]
    docs_x=[]
    docs_y=[]
    questionsP1=[]
    questionsP2=[]
    questionsP3=[]
    questionsP4=[]
    questionTag={}
    
    print( dataFileNames.get(inp) ) 
    with open(dataFileNames.get(inp)) as file:
        data = json.load(file)    
    
    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for proficiency in intent["proficiency"]:
            for questions in proficiency["questions"]:
                questions_list.append(questions["question"])
                for responses in questions["responses"]:        
                    wrds = tokenize(responses)
                    all_words.extend(wrds)
                    xy.append((wrds, questions["question"]))
                                
                if questions["tag"] in tags:
                    print(questions["tag"])
            
                if questions["tag"] not in tags:
                    tags.append(questions["tag"])
                        
                if proficiency["level"] == "P1":
                    questionsP1.append(questions["question"])
                    questionTag[questions["question"]]=questions["tag"]
                        
                if proficiency["level"] == "P2":
                    questionsP2.append(questions["question"])
                    questionTag[questions["question"]]=questions["tag"]
                    
                if proficiency["level"] == "P3":
                    questionsP3.append(questions["question"])
                    questionTag[questions["question"]]=questions["tag"]
                    
                if proficiency["level"] == "P4":
                    questionsP4.append(questions["question"])
                    questionTag[questions["question"]]=questions["tag"]

    #PyTorch Implementation

    ignore_words = ['?', '!', '.', ',']
    all_words = [stem(x) for x in all_words if x not in ignore_words]
    all_words = sorted(set(all_words))
    tags = sorted(set(tags))


    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    
    for tokenized_response, question in xy:
        bag = bag_of_words(tokenized_response, all_words)
        X_train.append(bag)
        label = questions_list.index( question)
        y_train.append(label)

    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)

    class ChatDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self):
            self.n_samples = len(X_train)
            self.x_data = X_train
            self.y_data = y_train
        
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]
        
        def __len__(self):
            return self.n_samples

    #HyperParameters
    batch_size = 8
    hidden_size = 8
    output_size = len(tags)
    input_size = len(X_train[0])
    learning_rate = 0.001
    num_epochs = 1000

    dataset = ChatDataset()
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset = dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 2)


    device = 'cpu'
    # print(device)
    global model_main
    model_main = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)

    try:
        print("Inside Try")
        data = torch.load(modelNames.get(inp))
        input_size = data["input_size"]
        hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
        output_size = data["output_size"]
        all_words = data["all_words"]
        questions_list = data["questions_list"]
        model_state = data["model_state"]

        model_main = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
        model_main.load_state_dict(model_state)
        model_main.eval()
    except:
        #loss and optimizer 
        print("Inside Except")
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_main.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            for (words, labels_net) in train_loader:
                words = words.to(device)
                labels_net = labels_net.to(device)

                #Forward
                outputs = model_main(words)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels_net)
                # print(loss)
                #backward and optimizer step
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                if (epoch + 1) % 100 == 0:
                    print(f'epoch {epoch + 1}/ {num_epochs}, loss={loss.item(): .4f}')

        print(f'final loss, loss={loss.item(): .4f}')

        ###############  Accuracy Calculation  ##############
        
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        # print(device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            for words, labels_net in train_loader:
                outputs = model_main(words)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                total += labels_net.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels_net).sum().item()

        print('Accuracy : %d %%' % ( 100 * correct / total ))

        #Saving the model

        data = {
            "model_state": model_main.state_dict(),
            "input_size": input_size,
            "output_size": output_size,
            "hidden_size": hidden_size,
            "all_words": all_words,
            "questions_list": questions_list
        }

        FILE = modelNames.get(inp)
        torch.save(data, FILE)
```

Comment: If possible, please provide error output in form of formatted text instead of image.

Comment: Also, please try to change number of workers to 0/1 and see if that helps

Comment: @Proko I changed num_workers to 0 and i am getting an error in loss statement...Expected Scalar Type long got int

Comment: @user9244584 that means there is a problem with pickling part of dataset/dataloader (your error output is unclear since I cannot read bewteen different stacktraces, if possible please remove ntlk data loading and other messages that are not relevant) The other error you got now is not related to your current problem. Please improve readability of the stacktrace and we will figure out what cannot be packed for multiprocessing